# reduce the memory when starting a Service(EGL mtrack too big)

Tags: android, performance, memory-management

First I declared the Service at manifest:

```
   <service android:name=".TestService"
        android:process=":test">
    </service>
```

Then, I create a Service that does nothing:

```
public class TestService extends Service{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I started a Service with

```
mContext.startService(new Intent(mContext, TestService.class));
```

in my Application,then I found the memory usage in 'Runing App' (get there by settings-> apps-> running) is 24M.And here is the meminfo I got:

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.mypush:test


Applications Memory Usage (kB):
Uptime: 79955214 Realtime: 87129943

** MEMINFO in pid 2452 [com.mypush:test] **
                   Pss  Private  Private  Swapped     Heap     Heap     Heap
                 Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
                ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
  Native Heap     2508     2468        0        0    12288     4916     7371
  Dalvik Heap     1354      956        0        0    22320    16969     5351
 Dalvik Other      400      400        0        0                           
        Stack      136      136        0        0                           
      Gfx dev      628      628        0        0                           
    Other dev        4        0        4        0                           
     .so mmap      860      336        4        0                           
    .apk mmap       29        0        0        0                           
    .ttf mmap        9        0        0        0                           
    .dex mmap      156        0        4        0                           
    .oat mmap      191        0        0        0                           
    .art mmap      564      268        0        0                           
   Other mmap       36        4        0        0                           
   EGL mtrack    13888    13888        0        0                           
    GL mtrack     3272     3272        0        0                           
      Unknown      152      152        0        0                           
        TOTAL    24187    22508       12        0    34608    21885    12722

 Objects
               Views:        0         ViewRootImpl:        0
         AppContexts:        3           Activities:        0
              Assets:        3        AssetManagers:        3
       Local Binders:        8        Proxy Binders:       13
       Parcel memory:        3         Parcel count:       12
    Death Recipients:        2      OpenSSL Sockets:        0

 SQL
         MEMORY_USED:        0
  PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW:        0          MALLOC_SIZE:        0
```

I am running on Android 5.0/Nexus5, and found some apps used a Service use less memory than mine.So I want to know why?

**Update**
I have found that the EGL mtrack dumped is about 13M, it is not normal for  a app that only has a empty Service.

Comment: Get rid of `android:process=":test"`, to save you the overhead of a second process.

Comment: @CommonsWare I use the second process because I want to communicate with other applications and want it run all the time.

Comment: "I use the second process because I want to communicate with other applications and want it run all the time" -- neither of those require a second process.

Comment: While I agree second process may not be needed for this case, any idea why would there by such huge EGL mtrack occupancy for a process that has no views or activities?